# group by, order by and take first

Tags: sql, groovy

I have a collection of type:

```
id name order
1  abc  2
1  abc  1
2  def  2
2  def  1
```

I want to get the result as

```
id name order
1  abc  1
2  def  1
```

That is, I first want to group by `id` and then order by `order`. I then want to take the one item from each group with lowest `order`.

Can this be done by some SQL query? I am using a PostgreSQL database.

If it's not possible in SQL then can I do this in Groovy (That is, I will first query all data and filter it in Groovy)?

Answer (score 0):

somrthing like this:

```
select id, name, min(order) from table group by id order by id asc
```